# Calculating the volume of a solid using triple integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The task says to compute the volume of the solid $A$ created when a cylinder $x^2+y^2 \leq R $ cuts through a ball $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4R^2$, where

$A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R | x^2+y^2 \leq R, x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4R^2\}$

I could really use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could describe A in [cylindrical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) 
$x=r \cos\theta $,
$y=r \sin\theta $,
$z=z$, then $A=\{(r,\theta,z):0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi, 0\leq r\leq \sqrt{R}, -\sqrt{4r^2+r^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{4r^2+r^2} \}$. Then the volume of this solid is $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R}} \int _{-\sqrt{4r^2+r^2}}^{\sqrt{4r^2+r^2}} r \;dz\; dr \; d\theta$ and it's easy to compute now.